# How to get a javascript httpGET to work in surveygizmo

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set up a test case for having surveygizmo push information back into drupal using httpGet. Here is what I have...

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://website.com", false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
return xmlHttp.responseText;
```

There will not be a function calling this, it should run once you reach the thankyou page, which is where this is placed. I am not sure how to get this to work. If anyone has an idea or know JS (Which I am very new too) I would totally appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is...?

Comment: I am trying to use javascript to send a url with variables attached to it to a page on a website.

Comment: How are you having problems with your current code, then?

Comment: I have a rule on it that say yes this page was visited. It is not getting triggered. So, my hope is that the above code or correct code will ping the url and trigger a rule for the website to do something. This is just a test to see if I can get it to ping.

Comment: Is this the same website as the page on which the code is running? If not, you might run into trouble (since browsers usually won't allow you to connect to other websites through JavaScript).

Comment: Also, it might be worth looking for errors in the JavaScript console (Ctrl-Shift-J in Chrome and Ctrl-Shift-K in Firefox, if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTP Connect action in SurveyGizmo for http post or get. See: https://help.surveygizmo.com/help/article/link/http-connect.

The javascript won't probably work because of the same-origin policy.

Comment: http connect action is a simple out of the box way to communicate with external dbs / webservices